# Trying to append a stream event to EventStore throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, eventstoredb

I am currently getting started with [EventStore](https://eventstore.com/) and I'm following the [Getting Started](https://eventstore.com/docs/getting-started/index.html?tabs=tabid-1%2Ctabid-dotnet-client%2Ctabid-dotnet-client-connect%2Ctabid-4) guide. And I just got stuck at the first step and don't know what I'm doing wrong...

The version I'm using now is **20.6.0**.

I'm trying to write an event using the .NET Core Client to my local instance (which is running because I can add events using the AdminUI). But I get an exception like `One or more errors occurred. (Connection 'ES-41230054-2026-4cdb-b2bb-a35824779863' was closed.)'`.

After a while trying to fix it, I went to the [.Net Client guide](https://eventstore.com/docs/dotnet-api/index.html?tabs=tabid-json-format) and pasted the exact same piece of code:

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            var conn = EventStoreConnection.Create(new Uri("tcp://admin:changeit@localhost:1113"));
            conn.ConnectAsync().Wait();

            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"a\":\"2\"}");
            var metadata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{}");
            var evt = new EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), "testEvent", true, data, metadata);

            conn.AppendToStreamAsync("test-stream", ExpectedVersion.Any, evt).Wait();

            var streamEvents = conn.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync("test-stream", 0, 1, false).Result;
            var returnedEvent = streamEvents.Events[0].Event;

            Console.WriteLine("Read event with data: {0}, metadata: {1}",
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnedEvent.Data),
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnedEvent.Metadata));
        }
    }
```

But the same exception is thrown when I get to this line:

```
conn.AppendToStreamAsync("test-stream", ExpectedVersion.Any, evt).Wait();
```

I tried different approaches when creating the connection but none worked so far.

I am wondering if I'm missing some configuration... If anyone has experienced this issue and would shred some light to this for me I'd be greatly thankful.

**Adding more info**

After activating the logging, I've seen the following:

- When trying to append the event, I get this output:

`[01,07:28:46.528,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': enqueueing message EventStore.ClientAPI.Internal.StartConnectionMessage..
[04,07:28:46.545,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': StartConnection.
[04,07:28:46.546,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': DiscoverEndPoint.
[04,07:28:46.549,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': enqueueing message EventStore.ClientAPI.Internal.EstablishTcpConnectionMessage..
[06,07:28:46.561,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': EstablishTcpConnection to [127.0.0.1:1113].
[05,07:28:46.582,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': enqueueing message EventStore.ClientAPI.Internal.StartOperationMessage..
[06,07:28:46.642,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': StartOperation enqueue AppendToStreamOperation, Stream: newstream, ExpectedVersion: -2, 10, 00:00:07..
[06,07:28:46.643,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': EnqueueOperation WAITING for Operation AppendToStreamOperation (a301f19c-bb92-4c53-a193-3a81582a49db): Stream: newstream, ExpectedVersion: -2, retry count: 0, created: 07:28:46.642, last updated: 07:28:46.642..
[08,07:28:48.702,DEBUG] TcpPackageConnection: connection to [127.0.0.1:1113, L, {69f92d44-54ab-4643-b540-23f89b796fcf}] failed. Error: ConnectionRefused.
[08,07:28:48.703,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': enqueueing message EventStore.ClientAPI.Internal.TcpConnectionClosedMessage..
[08,07:28:48.704,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': TCP connection to [127.0.0.1:1113, L, {69f92d44-54ab-4643-b540-23f89b796fcf}] closed..
[06,07:28:48.924,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': TimerTick checking reconnection....
[06,07:28:49.213,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': ExecuteOperation package WriteEvents, a301f19c-bb92-4c53-a193-3a81582a49db, Operation AppendToStreamOperation (a301f19c-bb92-4c53-a193-3a81582a49db): Stream: newstream, ExpectedVersion: -2, retry count: 0, created: 07:28:46.642, last updated: 07:28:48.935..
[06,07:28:49.229,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': DiscoverEndPoint.
[06,07:28:49.230,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': enqueueing message EventStore.ClientAPI.Internal.EstablishTcpConnectionMessage..
[04,07:28:49.231,DEBUG] EventStoreConnection 'ES-90357f8a-6c79-4638-909a-142c8ddb9a8b': EstablishTcpConnection to [127.0.0.1:1113].`

So this seems to say that the problem is that the port is not open, I tried disabling the firewall completelly with no luck.

- Also when I execute the command `EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --db ./db --log ./logs --dev` I noticed this in the outpue:

[image]

If I do `telnet 127.0.0.1 1113` it doesn't seem to be able to connect, but I'm not finding what's wrong. Any idea?

Comment: try removing `Wait` and `Result` and await asynchronous calls instead. These code bits are being rewritten for the new docs. Btw, it would be nice to know what version of EventStoreDB do you use.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev it's  20.6.0. And I already tried the async calls with no luck (

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I added some more info, trying my luck to see if someone spots the issue.

Comment: Okay so this does not an asnwer to my question, but using the docker container was much easier for me and now I've got it working. I configured it as described in this post and worked like a charm. https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/issues/2547#issuecomment-643278609

Comment: Yeah, you can use the same settings for enabling external ports for gRPC as described for the container, also when running ES locally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the exact same issue @devcrp

- your image with "Interfaces" pointed me directly to the missing flag when you start the server.

**solution (for 20.6.0 > ) is to add this flag when starting the event store**

```
--enable-external-tcp
```

I had a similar issue with the "Stream Browser" being disabled in Admin UI and it requires

```
--enable-atom-pub-over-http
```

And I had some other issues 
like not being aware of https was required to access the admin UI, http was stated in documentation and did not work (also new in 20.6.0) and how to get the config file to work (also due to an obsolete flag, ExtSecureTcpPort,  in the documentation, and missing info about TrustedRootCertificatesPath)

- here are some info on that with working config.yaml with TrustedRootCertificatesPath https://gist.github.com/JimiSweden/f8916a94bd3dab1ff07c940b9169c946

**If you look at the rows stating "DEPRECATION WARNING" in your console after the "Interfaces" there is a hint to why atom-pub-over-http and external-tcp needs to be enabled**

> Here is my console output with external-tcp and atom-pub-over-http enabled
>
> *what you see here has nothing to  do with firewalls etc, it is solely the output from event store.*

```
[28224, 1,22:27:51.677,INF]
INTERFACES
External TCP (Protobuf)
        Enabled : True
        Port    : 1113
HTTP (AtomPub)
        Enabled : True
        Port    : 2113

[28224, 1,22:27:51.678,WRN]
 DEPRECATION WARNING: AtomPub over HTTP Interface has been deprecated as of version 20.02. It is recommended to use gRPC instead.

[28224, 1,22:27:51.678,WRN]
 DEPRECATION WARNING: The Legacy TCP Client Interface has been deprecated as of version 20.02. The External TCP Interface can be re-enabled with the 'EnableExternalTCP' option. It is recommended to use gRPC instead.
```

> **This is my working start command**
> (in a file called '.\eventstore start command.ps1' to make it simpler to run the server)

[image: screen capture of powershell file as start command]

```
EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --db ./db --log ./logs --config=config.yaml --enable-atom-pub-over-http --enable-external-tcp --run-projections=all --start-standard-projections=true
```

Comment: here are more details on news and breaking changes for 20.6.0
https://eventstore.com/blog/event-store-20.6.0-release/ 
(haven't yet found out how to use the new gRPC client , searching for examples.. now going through the test and src folder in the project https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore-Client-Dotnet)

Comment: and here are my lab files , also with a working gRPC client https://github.com/JimiSweden/eventstore-getting-started